# ValueError: expected convolution2d_input_8 to have shape (None, 3, 150, 150) but got array with shape (32, 150, 150, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I got the following error

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected convolution2d_input_8 to have shape (None, 3, 150, 150) but got array with shape (32, 150, 150, 3)

I think its is because of the dim_ordering. I am using tensorflow backend.
But if I remove it I get another error:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'Conv2D_17' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,74,16], [3,3,16,32].

```
import keras
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)  # reproducibility

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense


# expected image size
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
# folder containing the images on which
# the network will train. The train folder 
# has two sub folders, dogs and cats.
train_data_dir = 'C:/Users/Ishan Sohony/Downloads/Compressed/train'
# folder containing the validation samples
# folder structure is same as the training folder
validation_data_dir = 'C:/Users/Ishan Sohony/Downloads/Compressed/test1'
# how many images to be considered for training
train_samples = 2000
# how many images to be used for validation
validation_samples = 800
# how many runs will the network make
# over the training set before starting on
# validation
epoch = 50
# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
# we are generating a lot of transformed images so that the model
# can handle variety in the real world scenario
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
# this section is actually taking images from the folder
# and passing on to the ImageGenerator which then
# creates a lot of transformed versions

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
# ** Model Begins **
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, img_width, img_height),dim_ordering='th'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
# ** Model Ends **
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


# this is where the actual processing happens
# it will take some time to run this step.
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=train_samples,
        nb_epoch=epoch,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        nb_val_samples=validation_samples)

model.save_weights('trial.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Input shape
>
> 4D tensor with shape: (samples, channels, rows, cols) if
>   dim_ordering='th' or 4D tensor with shape: (samples, rows, cols,
>   channels) if dim_ordering='tf'.
>
> Output shape
>
> 4D tensor with shape: (samples, nb_filter, new_rows, new_cols) if
>   dim_ordering='th' or 4D tensor with shape: (samples, new_rows,
>   new_cols, nb_filter) if dim_ordering='tf'. rows and cols values might
>   have changed due to padding.
>   [source](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d)

Indeed it comes from dimension ordering. 
Not only the input must be different when using Theano or Tensorflow, the output will be too.

If I understand correctly, you should use tf backend as usual, but then change your input shape to become (150,150,3). 
If you really want to change to Theano, consider setting dim_ordering to theano for **all** of the convolutionnal layers, so that they can "speak" to each other regarding output and input shapes.

Does this help?